# Is there a way to use Redis in a Spring Boot App without configuring any Redis clients

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I have read some articles and in them Jedis or Lettuce client is used to connect and to configure Redis but I have found another article (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-redis-cache)
which says "Spring Boot will auto-configure a RedisCacheManager" and has provided code for this as well.

When I'm trying this I'm getting following error :

```
2023-07-21T13:48:24.977+05:30 ERROR 24328 --- \[nio-8449-exec-1\] o.a.c.c.C.\[.\[.\[/\].\[dispatcherServlet\]    : Servlet.service() for servlet \[dispatcherServlet\] in context with path \[\] threw exception \[Request processing failed: org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis\] with root cause

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:946) \~\[na:na\]
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:337) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:776) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final\]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) \~\[netty-common-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final\]
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) \~\[netty-common-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final\]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) \~\[netty-common-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final\]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) \~\[na:na\]
```

application.properties :

```
spring.redis.cluster.nodes=host:6379
spring.redis.cluster.max-redirects=3
REDIS_CACHE_ENABLE=true
spring.redis.host=
spring.redis.port=6379
redis.Cluster=true
```

Config file :

```
@Configuration
public class CacheConfig {

    @Bean
    public RedisCacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration() {
        return RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
          .entryTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(60))
          .disableCachingNullValues()
          .serializeValuesWith(SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer()));
    }

}
```

Dependencies I have added apart from necessary ones, pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I am trying to get Spring Boot to auto-configure Redis with default configurations and then I'll like to modify few of this configurations.

Please, suggest a solution for this or another way achieve same. Thank you.